# Swiftui scaleEffect translation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am scaling a SwiftUI rectangle.

When using `scaleEffect`, the object is translated to the middle of the view ? With which amount is that translation ? Is it dependent to the scaleFactor I have given ?

```
let scaleFactor = 0.2


Rectangle().scaleEffect(scaleFactor, anchor:.center)
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: Imaging you copy-pasted this line in pretty new project or Playground... and what will you see from it? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added diagram to show what I mean.